# NodeJS fetch promise callback pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have this code:

```
fetch(url).then(response => {
  const json = response.json();
  console.log('simplest possible fetch', json, json.where);
});
```

In the console I get:

```
simplest possible fetch Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined} undefined
```

I get this *most* of the time. Sometimes I get the "success" status. To me this implies the callback is being run before the fetch promise has resolved.

I want the function to be run only when the fetch completes. How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise, use `then` callback to get the data:

> The json() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log('simplest possible fetch', data, data.where));
```

Comment: awesome answer alex!! :) @alexmac