# Returning the JSON content from a fetch but only getting the Promise

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have code like this:

```
function fetchUsers(cb) {
    fetch(API_BASE + '/users/').then(checkStatus)
                               .then(parseJSON)
                               .then(cb);
}
```

If I pass `cb` so that it takes the JSON and stores it or applies it all is well.

What I would prefer is something like this:

```
function fetchUsers(cb) {
    return fetch(API_BASE + '/users/').then(checkStatus)
                                      .then(parseJSON)
                                      .then(data => { return data });
}
```

But this does not work because the returned `data` is still a Promise.
There are several questions on SO about Promises and fetch. [NodeJS fetch promise callback pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275859/nodejs-fetch-promise-callback-pending) or [Get the data from fetch -> promise -> response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378302/get-the-data-from-fetch-promise-response) for instance. But I could not find one that explains why the work has to happen within the `then` call. Is there an idiomatic way to block until the Promise is resolved?

Comment: `return fetch`  this is always going to return promise.  Is there any reason you can't just do `fetchUsers.then()`, If you want a blocking version of fetch, your only option currently is XMLHttpRequest, but even then it's rapidly been depreciated on the main thread.  If you don't like callbacks & thenables, have a look at async / await, these work with Promises.

Comment: This was the point of my question. I cannot find an explanation of WHY this matters. How would `fetchUsers.then` be any different from what I posted?Why does the Promise have to be handled in a callback?

Comment: Getting marked duplicate without a pointer is not helpful. I actually linked two questions which are similar but miss my question.

Comment: `Why does the Promise have to be handled in a callback?`  because the calling end would have to block otherwise, and that's bad.  The best way to look like it's blocking is use asyn/await, but in the background it's just doing the thenables for you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Keith. Sorry I can't give you points.